# Destroy prefab instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am implementing a smoke prefab in my game. The idea is to create 3 different instances of the prefab (in different positions) then destroy them according to a toggle button. The problem the instances are not being destroyed and I have no idea why.

This is my script:

```
class Smoke1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public GameObject myPrefab;
    public GameObject canvasObject;

    public static GameObject newSmoke1;
    public static GameObject newSmoke2;
    public static GameObject newSmoke3;

    public int toggle1;
    public int toggle2;
    public int toggle3;

    public Vector3 smokeposition1 = new Vector3 (397, -394, 90);
    public Vector3 smokeposition2 = new Vector3(414, -402, 90);
    public Vector3 smokeposition3 = new Vector3(432, -410, 90);

    string newSmoke;


    void Start()
        {
        i = 1;
        toggle1 = 2;
        toggle2 = 2;
        toggle3 = 2;
        newinstance(smokeposition1, newSmoke1);
        newinstance(smokeposition2, newSmoke2);
        newinstance(smokeposition3, newSmoke3);
        }

    void Update()
        {

        togglecheck(ThermoElectric.t1Bool, toggle1, newSmoke1, smokeposition1);
        togglecheck(ThermoElectric.t2Bool, toggle2, newSmoke2, smokeposition2);
        togglecheck(ThermoElectric.t3Bool, toggle3, newSmoke3, smokeposition3);
        }

    void newinstance(Vector3 smokeposition, GameObject smokeinstance)
        {
        smokeinstance = Instantiate(myPrefab, smokeposition, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        smokeinstance.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
        smokeinstance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        smokeinstance.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = new Color(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);

        }

    void togglecheck(bool turbine, int togglei, GameObject smokeinstancet, Vector3 smokeposition)
        {

        if (turbine == true && togglei == 1)
            {
            newinstance(smokeposition, smokeinstancet);
            togglei = 2;
            }

        if (turbine == false && togglei == 2)
            {
            Destroy(smokeinstancet, 0.1f);
            togglei = 1;
            }
        }
}
```

The bools are working and the if conditions are met, but the prefabs don't get destroyed..Can you help?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html
When did you check if you elements are destoyed? _"Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but will always be done before rendering."_

Comment: When the game runs I see that the prefabs are not destroyed when I change the toggle.

Comment: I see no reason for delay, the loop should finish right away.

Comment: When you debug it, does it jump to  `Destroy(smokeinstancet, 0.1f);` or skips it?

Comment: I inserted a Debug.Log in the line after it and it ran. I saw the result in the inspector.

Comment: I don't think you can have static Gameobjects. I would remove static

Comment: I am not sure too but I removed the static and the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bools are working and the if conditions are met, but the prefabs
>   don't get destroyed..Can you help?

**1**.You shouldn't be destroying prefabs. You should only destroy the GameObject created with `Instantiate`.

**2**.Remove the statics from the GameObject. I am sure you don't need that.

If you are %100 sure sure that the if conditions are met then the `newinstance` function is the problem.If you are not sure, put `Debug.Log` inside  `if (turbine == false && togglei == 2)` to verify that this condition is met because without that, `Destroy(smokeinstancet, 0.1f);` wont be called.

Problem  with the `newinstance` function.

```
void newinstance(Vector3 smokeposition, GameObject smokeinstance)
{
    smokeinstance = Instantiate(myPrefab, smokeposition, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
    smokeinstance.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
    smokeinstance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

    smokeinstance.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = new Color(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
}
```

The `smokeinstance = Instantiate(myPrefab, smokeposition, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;` code will assign the instantiated GameObject to the local variable in the parameter called `smokeinstance`. It will not assign it to the GameObjects passed into it such as `newSmoke1`,`newSmoke2` and `newSmoke3`.

```
newinstance(smokeposition1, newSmoke1);
newinstance(smokeposition2, newSmoke2);
newinstance(smokeposition3, newSmoke3);
```

**SOLUTION**:

*You have 2 solutions*:

**1**.Use the `ref` or `out` keyword. In this case, we will just use the `ref` keyword.

```
void newinstance(Vector3 smokeposition, ref GameObject smokeinstance)
{
 ......
}
```

then also use `ref` while calling it.

```
newinstance(smokeposition1, ref newSmoke1);
newinstance(smokeposition2, ref newSmoke2);
newinstance(smokeposition3, ref newSmoke3);
```

**2**.Make `newinstance` function return `GameObject` instead of `void`.

```
GameObject newinstance(Vector3 smokeposition)
{
    GameObject smokeinstance = Instantiate(myPrefab, smokeposition, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0));
}
```

then call it:

```
newSmoke1 = newinstance(smokeposition1);
newSmoke2 = newinstance(smokeposition2);
newSmoke3 = newinstance(smokeposition3);
```

Any one of this should solve your problem.

Comment: You are the man! Right on spot. I used the solution 1 and did the same for the toggle1, toggle2 and toggle 3 and it worked! I understand what ref is for now! Thanks so much!